# How to parse usb raw data according to usb report descriptor?

Tags: usb

I have got the report descriptor from my usb HID device, and I want to parse the raw data with the report descriptor. However I searched the Internet only to find how to parse using existing tools, not how to parse by yourself( e.g. if I get a report descriptor from any usb device, then with the report descriptor I can parse the data from it, and output the meaning, perhaps the report descriptor is a custom one.)

I have read several articles about how to parse data from a keyboard or a mouse, as the keyboard or the mouse have a common data pattern they don't mention how to use report descriptor to help with your analysis. So if I get a new device (not keyboard or mouse but some other HID device), the only thing I can rely on is the HID report descriptor( The report descriptor may be vendor specific). However none of these articles say how to parse data with custom report descriptor.

Could anyone offer me a sample, which shows the whole process of parsing the report descriptor and parsing the usb raw data accordingly? Thanks!